# Can you reinterpret an array of doubles as a struct containing an array of doubles?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, memory-alignment, type-punning

I am using a library which represents an array of 3D Cartesian vectors as sequential one-dimensional array of `double`s, where three subsequent entries correspond to the Cartesian components of one vector. I also have a self-written class `Vector3` for 3D vectors which implements some arithmetics. I would like to treat this plain `double` array as an array of `Vector3` objects instead, as in the following:

```
class Vector3 {
  // Some functions and operators
  double m_pData[3]; // the components of the vector
};

double *pd = GetFromLibrary(); // The input raw data
Vector3 *pv = (Vector3*)pd; // Treat raw data as array of objects...

pv[3].m_pData[1] = 17.5; // Set the Y component of the fourth vector
```

I tried this code on several different compilers and platforms, and it works fine. From a naive view, it should of course always work, but I am not sure if there could arise any alignment issues. Does the C++ standard state that this is allowed? If not, is there any way how I could modify the code to make it standard conforming without copying the data to a different memory location?

Or to ask in a different way: Does the standard guarantee that a plain array of `Vector3` has all of its `double` data members without gaps, our could it happen that the compiler inserts some padding for alignment (maybe to multiples of 32 bytes)?

Comment: padding is not standardized, but i have never seen a compiler with `double` not being aligned to 8 bytes by default, whoever does otherwise will make his binaries unable to link to OS binaries .... so i don't think this will ever change for desktop compilers, this may not be true for embedded applications.

Comment: There cannot be any padding in an array, but there *can* be padding in a struct or class. So no guarantees about the layout. How long does it take to copy 3 doubles?

Comment: @BoP: As the array has many vectors, it is more like 3 million doubles in reality.

Comment: If you read [What is the strict aliasing rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/98650/9837301) you might decide to focus your question on how to accomplish what you want without copying memory...

Comment: You could make a `Vector3Array` instead and just provide accessors to the underlying array. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/Me5benavc). With iterators added it would almost feel like a "normal" container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if alignment and size/layout are correct, it is technically still UB per standard. You can't cast to some type (here `Vector3`) pretending that an object of that type exists when it was never explicitly or implicitly created. The result will instead be a pointer that still points to the original `double` object, but with mismatched expression type, so that any member access will have undefined behavior, as will any pointer arithmetic such as in `pv[3]`. In practice compilers probably won't care that much (but neither do I know whether they are committed to allow such a use, now or in the future).

For alignment itself: The alignment requirement of `Vector3` may technically be stricter than that of `double`, so that the pointer returned by `GetFromLibrary` may be misaligned. That's something to look up in the ABI specification you are relying on or by adding `static_assert(alignof(Vector3) <= alignof(double));`. However, I don't think any ABI in common use does that.

For other layout issues: Technically there can be padding at the end of `Vector3`. However, again, I am not aware of any ABI that behaves like this. And you can verify this too with `static_assert(sizeof(Vector3) == sizeof(double)*3);`. Padding before the array member or inbetween array elements is not permitted.

---

Note that I assume in the above that your class is [*standard-layout*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/classes#Standard-layout_class) and doesn't have any further non-static data members or any base classes. This also means no `virtual` member functions, etc.

If that is not the case, then there can also be padding before the array member and it is much less likely that size and alignment will be correct (especially if there are `virtual` functions). Again, the concrete layout will be specified either way in the applicable ABI specification.

---

Also, if instead of using the same scalar type (`double`) in both instances, you used mismatched scalar types (e.g. `double` in `Vector3`, but pointer into a `uint64_t` array), then compilers will not be lenient. This would be a direct aliasing violation that is itself UB and compilers do optimize on, so that behavior will silently not be as expected.

Comment: Given this, perhaps it makes sense to have the vector3 class use static methods that operate on `double*` instead of itself?  (It would assume the double has 3 members, not UB as long as it never points past the end of the main array)

Comment: @DaveS Or just free functions (potentially in a namespace), yes. But that won't allow nice array indexing syntax which is what OP seems to be after and I don't think there is any way to achieve that without UB or copying.

Comment: This answer would be a good fit for the dupe target too, since that one doesn't have great answers that go into much detail yet.

Comment: @JanSchultke I think if you take the top answers there together you already have the gist of it. I don't really feel like rewriting a full answer there (which would be necessary since the example is a bit different). If you'd like to, feel free to post your own answer there, taking whatever you need from mine here.